# Trigger Jenkins job via Github webhook without passing username password in plain text

Tags: github, jenkins

I have a Jenkins setup which requires a username and password for login
I am using Github webhook to trigger a build on this jenkins.
Currently I am passing username and password in the URL itself and it's working fine.
https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@jenkins.xyz.in/view/dev/job/uploadTest/buildWithParameters

[Github Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPKOk.png)

Is there any other secure way to send username and password

Comment: What do you mean with "secure". Actually, the credentials are transmitted using https. You can assure with wireshark.

Comment: We have setup an ngrock tunnel between our jenkins and outside. So we don't want to send our username and password in plain text to ngrock

Answer (score 0):

See the [official documentation for how to integrate GitHub and Jenkins](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/224543927-GitHub-Integration-Webhooks).  TL;DR:  install the GitHub Integration plugin, which automatically manages webhooks for you (it creates tokens for GitHub to use to trigger jobs).